# AJAX Mouse Over Image, Display HTML Content

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, image, mouseover

I'm trying to use AJAX to display html content when mousing over an image. My code seems good but doesn't seem to work. deakin-campus / discover-deakin are the html pages I'm trying to display.

The code below displays no content, but if I add some alerts throughout the code; the html text is displayed.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" >

var asyncRequest;

function getContent(url)
{
    try
    {

        asyncRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();


        asyncRequest.open( 'GET', url, true );


        asyncRequest.send(null);

    asyncRequest.onreadystatechange = stateChange();



    }
    catch (exception)
    {

            alert("error");

    }
}

function stateChange()
{


    if (asyncRequest.readyState == 4 && asyncRequest.status == 200)
    {

        document.getElementById('ContentArea').innerHTML= asyncRequest.responseText;
    }
}

function clearContent()
{
    document.getElementById('ContentArea').innerHTML = '';
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<img src="deakin-campus.jpg" width="71" height="71"
onmouseover = 'getContent("deakin-campus.html")'
onmouseout = 'clearContent()' />

<img src="discover-deakin.jpg" width="71" height="71"
onmouseover = 'getContent("discover-deakin.html")'
onmouseout = 'clearContent()' />

<div id="ContentArea">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass the function reference... so no "()".

```
asyncRequest.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
```

Also do this before .send method is called.